# Why is the second variable passed as a reference and const

Tags: c++

Why isn't `first` passed as a reference and const as well?

```
template <typename Iterator>
    int distance(Iterator first, const Iterator & last) {
    int count;
    for ( ; first != last; first++)
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you find this code snippet?

Comment: @juanchopanza it was a solution to an exercise we had to do at uni

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It cannot be `const` because it is incremented inside the function, and it is not passed by reference because it probably makes no sense to do so for the caller.

Furthermore, if it were non-const reference, it would not be possible to use a temporary. For example, you wouldn't be able to do tis:

```
std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
auto distance = std::distance(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Answer (score 6):

Because it is changed inside the function, so it can't be const. However, you wouldn't want its state (its value) to change outside the function, so it's passed by-value (not reference).

Answer (score 4):

A better question is why the second argument is passed by const reference, since the signature defined in the standard is:

```
template <typename Iterator>
typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
distance(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

That is, both by value.

Answer (score 1):

Because if we don't want to modify the caller's value we would need to create a copy anyway.